# Unexpected invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go

I'm getting a runtime error for an invalid memory address.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x4e0f24]

goroutine 1192592 [running]:
panic(0x793540, 0xc420010040)
#011/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
foobar/sd.(*Channel).Attributes(0x0, 0xc420110101, 0xc42278f9b0, 0x9)
#011/home/app/go/src/foobar/sd/channel.go:36 +0x54
```

channel.go looks like this:

```
35 func (m *Channel) Attributes() (*ChannelAttrs, error) {
36    redisHash := "sd:channels:" + m.hash
37
38    rc := m.ctx.RedisPool.Get()
39    values, err := redis.Values(rc.Do("HGETALL", redisHash))
40    rc.Close()
41    if err != nil {
42        return nil, err
43    }
44    attrs := ChannelAttrs{}
45    redis.ScanStruct(values, &attrs)
46    return &attrs, nil
47 }
```

How is it possible that the line 36 is causing this? Is it somehow possible for `m` to be nil? If so, how?

Note: hash is defined as string

Comment: Is `m` `nil` in the code that calls this?

Comment: I don't know, this happens rarely in production code. I haven't found a way to replicate it. Is it even possible for m to be nil in go?

Comment: You have missed reffering m [Updated](https://play.golang.org/p/j9T0dQ8-oH)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This means that `Attributes` is being called with receiver `m` as `nil`.

In principle methods can be called with `nil` receivers (and this may even be useful if they check for `nil`) - see [here](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/wcrZ3P1zeAk) - but this particular method `Attributes()` is not designed to be called with a `nil` receiver, as `m` is being dereferenced without a `nil` check. This (method being called with a `nil` receiver `m`) is what is happening in your calling code.

See a simplified example [on the playground here](https://play.golang.org/p/d-MxAtKMPG), and note that commenting out `+ m.hash` makes the whole thing work fine, as [here](http://play.golang.org/p/KSQ0cMxkmb).

Code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Channel struct {
    hash string
}

func (m *Channel) Attributes() {
    r := "x" + m.hash
    fmt.Println(r)
}

func main() {
    var c *Channel
    c.Attributes()
}
```

The output of which is:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0xffffffff addr=0x0 pc=0x20131]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x102360, 0x1040a038)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x720
main.(*Channel).Attributes(0x0, 0x104000f0)
/tmp/sandbox285779060/main.go:12 +0x131
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox285779060/main.go:18 +0x20
```

Comment: Oh I see, it confuses me that the error is for the Attributes function line. Is it ever usable to call a function on a nil object?

Comment: The problem is *dereferencing* the nil pointer in `m.hash`. If you comment out `+ m.hash` it will be fine - see https://play.golang.org/p/KSQ0cMxkmb - (i.e. yes, it's ok to call a function with a `nil` object if you do not dereference the pointer).